tippy-js works on my desktop with VSC and live server, not online
You can see the problem here: "https://levillagevertical.com/journaux/journaux.html". When you hover the main heading(JOURNAUX) a first tooltip is triggered (Subura News), the first instance of tippy (template) works fine throughout the site but the data-tippy-content does not. It is mostly a static HTML website with a couple of PHP includes for header, footer...
<div class="pageheading" id="journaux">
  <h1>Journaux</h1>
</div>
<div class="template" id="template">
  <h4>
    <a href="/journaux/suburanews.html">Subura News</a>
    <br />
    Pauvre France d'en-haut! Sincèrement, je compatis.
  </h4>
  <p>
    De tant vouloir fourguer à la France d'en-bas pour des lanternes ses vessies, ...
  </p>
</div>
<ul class="navig inline">
  <li 
    id="riante" 
    data-tippy-content="Subura News, À la une, Lire la suite, M… à Marianne, Apologie d\'Attal sans i, Contresens et Barbarismes, La boucle se boucla">
    <a href="#riante">Honteuses Calomnies</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a 
      href="#campagnes" 
      id="campagnes" 
      data-tippy-content="Municipales 2008, Présidentielles 2022, Mort de Rire, Européennes 2024">
      Journal de Campagnes
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>

<script>
  const template = document.getElementById("template");
  tippy("#journaux", {
    content: template.innerHTML,
    allowHTML: true,
    interactive: true,
    theme: "village_4",
    placement: "bottom",
  });

  tippy('[data-tippy-content]');
</script>

I have tried this:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  tippy('[data-tippy-content]');
})


I also tried to include const template = document.getElementById... inside the function. Does not work either.
